# How to connect different firebase databases to release/beta/alpha versions?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, sha1, sha

I have one app that supposed to have different Firebase database, Firebase storage for release and beta versions but i'm not able to connect Firebase to more than one project because SHA certificate fingerprints supposed to be different.

Here is error from Firebase:
[image: Firebase error]

At the same time I cannot upload on Google Play app with different signing certificates.

Here is error from Google Play Console:
[image: Google play error]

Is it possible to somehow have different Firebase database for one project? Both versions are going to Google Play, both supposed to be signed, so debug builds will not work in current situation.

Comment: _On a screenshot SHA1 keys are not real_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to have different Firebase database for one project.
Do not add SHA1 keys. As mentioned in the error 'you can omit the SHA1'

in any one firebase project, go to authentication -> SIGN-IN METHOD-> GOOGLE , click edit option, it will open up a view, as in the pic below

[image]

Expand 'Whitelist client ids *' Click on add, add the **client Id** of the other firebase project, you can find this in the google-services.json.

```
"oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "583957834728-jprivhot8johm3himgkmhqnnlmh1nldj.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
```

First initialize a FirebaseApp instance for that other Firebase project

```
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
       .setApplicationId("1:530266078999:android:481c4ecf3253701e") // Required for Analytics.
       .setApiKey("AIzaSyBRxOyIj5dJkKgAVPXRLYFkdZwh2Xxq51k") // Required for Auth.
       .setDatabaseUrl("https://project-1765055333176374514.firebaseio.com/") // Required for RTDB.
       .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this /* Context */, options, "secondary");
```

applicationid, Apikey and URL should be of secondary database. These can be found here settings->project settings->General tab

To authenticate secondary database.

```
AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
            FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary");
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance(app).signInWithCredential(credential)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Log.w(TAG, getString(R.string.signin_authentication_failed_msg), task.getException());
                                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this,
                                        getString(R.string.signin_authentication_failed),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            }
                      else {
                               //do something - login sucess

                        }
                        }
                    });
```

this should fix the authentication part.

Next part how to access the second firebase database??

Accessing the secondary Firebase Project

```
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary");
            FirebaseDatabase secondaryDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app);

            TestEntry testEntry = new TestEntry(orderId);

            DatabaseReference orderIdReference = secondaryDatabase.
                    getReference().child(orderId);

            Log.d("Secondary db", orderIdReference.toString());

            orderIdReference.setValue(testEntry);
```

source: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html

Comment: Thank you very much!
I'll try your solution and will reply soon

Comment: I have edited my answer, I have added the code to authenticate secondary firebase project.